# PowerPoint VBA text change only on presentation view

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I have text on slide 2 and I have macro with on click to change it's value, but it changes value in presentation file, but I want to change it's value only on view (presentation) and file should be as it was on start.

My macro: `ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "new text"`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail code and error... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: There's only the presentation and several ways of looking at it (normal, slide show, etc). If you make changes to the presentation in any view, the changes will be reflected in all views. You could make changes then close the presentation w/o saving or you could possibly set the text to a known starting value upon starting the slide show.